# Как упростить перебор всех комбинаций

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Есть объект:

```
const letters = {
    1: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    2: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    3: ['g', 'h', 'i'],
    4: ['j', 'k', 'l'],
    5: ['m', 'n', 'o'],
    6: ['p', 'q', 'r'],
    7: ['s', 't', 'u'],
    8: ['v', 'w', 'x'],
    9: ['y', 'z']
}
```

Необходимо написать функцию, которая вернет все возможные комбинации из переданных строкой чисел. Я сделал таким образом:

```
const func = (str) => {
  if (str.length === 0) return []

  const strArr = str.split('')
  const result = []
  
  const arrays = strArr.map(item => letters[item])

  if (strArr.length === 1) return arrays[0]
  
  for (let letterIndex = 0; letterIndex < arrays[0].length; letterIndex++) {
    const word = arrays[0][letterIndex]

    for (let arrayIndex = 1; arrayIndex < arrays.length; arrayIndex++) {
      
      for (let letterArrayIndex = 0; letterArrayIndex < arrays[arrayIndex].length; letterArrayIndex++) {
        const secondWord = word + arrays[arrayIndex][letterArrayIndex]
        
        if (arrays.length > 2) {
          for (let restArrays = arrayIndex + 1; restArrays < arrays.length; restArrays++) {
            for (let i = 0; i < arrays[restArrays].length; i++) {
              result.push(secondWord + arrays[restArrays][i])
            }
          }
        } else {
          result.push(secondWord)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  return result
}
```

Ожидаемые выводы:

```
func('') => []
func('2') => ['d', 'e', 'f']
func('23') => ["dg","dh","di","eg","eh","ei","fg","fh","fi"]
```

Но очевидно, что это выглядит стремно. Я чувствую, что это можно решить как то красиво рекурсией, но в голову не лезет, как это сделать.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что двузначных чисел не будет в `letters`?

Comment: @EzioMercer если вы подразумеваете двузначный ключ объекта, то нет, это статичный алфавит привязанный к ключам, где у каждого индекса саб массивов есть только 1 буква.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант без рекурсии:

```js
const letters = {
    1: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    2: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    3: ['g', 'h', 'i'],
    4: ['j', 'k', 'l'],
    5: ['m', 'n', 'o'],
    6: ['p', 'q', 'r'],
    7: ['s', 't', 'u'],
    8: ['v', 'w', 'x'],
    9: ['y', 'z']
};

const getAllCombinationsOfTwoArr = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const result = [];
  
  for (const str1 of arr1) {
    for (const str2 of arr2) {
      result.push(str1 + str2);
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

const getAllCombinations = (str, alphabet) => {
  if (str.length === 0) return [];
  
  const rowsNum = str.split('');
  let result = [''];
  
  for (const rowNum of rowsNum) {
    result = getAllCombinationsOfTwoArr(result, alphabet[rowNum]);
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(getAllCombinations('', letters));
console.log(getAllCombinations('1', letters));
console.log(getAllCombinations('12', letters));
console.log(getAllCombinations('123', letters));
```

Comment: `return [];` -> `return [''];`

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Так автор сказал же `func('') => []`

Comment: Я считаю что автор в данном случае ошибается. Задача состоит в выдаче всех возможных строк определённой длины. Если длина нулевая, надо выдавать единственный правильный ответ - пустую строку. Не всегда надо ходить на поводу у автора. В конце концов он задаёт вопрос, значит что-то ему не понятно. :)

Comment: @EzioMercer тоже благодарю, но с рекурсией красивей выглядит. По поводу строки с 0 длиной, все таки должен возвращаться пустой массив, такое тз в задаче.

Comment: @MrYogurt, проблема рекурсивного варианта в том что он в принципе не может вернуть пустой массив. :(. Чтобы это добиться придётся приделывать костыли. Рекомендую вам принять этот ответ.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Понял вашу точку зрения, согласен в целом, но обычно авторы такие задания делают, когда выполняют тренировочную задачу, и там от них трубуют всякое. Потому обычно предпочитаю не исправлять ожидаемые выводы)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy не понимаю, почему не может? Если вернуть пустой массив при вызове func сразу, то рекурсия и не запускается.

Comment: @MrYogurt, вы сами попробуйте. `func` начнёт всегда возвращать пустые массивы. При любых аргументах.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy а, понял, вы правы, упустил этот момент. Тогда изменил правильный ответ, но все же через рекурсию мне нравится больше, пусть и чуть покостылить надо, хотя на собесе мне будет тяжело таким образом решать.

Comment: @MrYogurt Если сильно хочется ответ с рекурсией применить, то можно написать простую функцию, которая сначала сделает проверку входных аргументов и если всё окей, то вызовет рекурсивную фцнкцию, а если что-то не так то вернёт пустой массив

Comment: @EzioMercer как поправить я знаю, это уже не проблема

Answer (score 2):

Требование `func('') => []` я заменил на `func('') => ['']`. Так более логично.

```js
     const letters = {
        1: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        2: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
        3: ['g', 'h', 'i'],
        4: ['j', 'k', 'l'],
        5: ['m', 'n', 'o'],
        6: ['p', 'q', 'r'],
        7: ['s', 't', 'u'],
        8: ['v', 'w', 'x'],
        9: ['y', 'z']
    }
    
    const func = digits => {
        if (digits.length === 0) {
            return [''];
        }
        const result = [];
        const strs = func(digits.substring(1));
        for (const c of letters[+digits[0]]) {
            for (const s of strs) {
                result.push(c + s);
            }
        }
        return result;
    };
    
    console.log(func('23'));
```

Comment: Благодарю, то что нужно.